# Convert raw SQL to use Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I convert the following complex SQL query to use the Eloquent query builder? I want to use methods such as `join()` and `where()`, `get()` etc.

The below query returns a list of locations along with counts for vouchers that have been redeemed.

```sql
select 
        a.location_name,
        '' as dates,
        a.places,
        sum(netvalue155), 
        sum(netvalue135) from
        (
            select 
                l.id,
                l.location_name,
                b.places,
                case when v.net_value = 155 then 1 else 0 end as netvalue155,
                case when v.net_value = 135 then 1 else 0 end as netvalue135
            from locations l 
                left join bookings b on l.id = b.location_id 
                left join vouchers v on  b.voucher_code = v.voucher_code
        ) a
        right join locations l on l.id = a.id
    group by a.location_name
```

**EDIT**

I am trying the below code, which throws the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sub.id' in on clause`

```
$subQuery = DB::table('locations')
        ->select(
            'locations.id',
            'locations.location_name',
            DB::raw('"'.$request->get('dates').'" as dates'),
            DB::raw('sum(bookings.id) as number'),
            DB::raw('round(sum(bookings.final_price/1.2), 2) as paidbycard'),
            DB::raw('case when bookings.voucher_value = 155 then round(sum(bookings.voucher_value/1.2), 2) else 0.00 end as voucher155'),
            DB::raw('case when bookings.voucher_value = 135 then round(sum(bookings.voucher_value/1.2), 2) else 0.00 end as voucher135'),
            DB::raw('case when bookings.transfer_fee = 10 then round(sum(bookings.transfer_fee/1.2), 2) else 0.00 end as transfer_fee'))
        ->leftJoin('bookings', 'locations.id', '=', 'bookings.location_id');

    $meatBookQuery = DB::table('orders')->select(DB::raw('sum(orders_items.price) as total'))
        ->join('orders_items', 'orders.id', '=', 'orders_items.order_id')
        ->where('orders_items.item_name', 'The Meat Book');

    $booking = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as sub, ({$meatBookQuery->toSql()}) as meatBook"))
        ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
        ->mergeBindings($meatBookQuery)
        ->select('sub.location_name', 'sub.dates', 'sub.number', 'sub.paidbycard', 'sub.voucher155', 'sub.voucher135', 'sub.transfer_fee', DB::raw('round(sum(sub.voucher155 + sub.voucher135 + sub.transfer_fee + sub.paidbycard), 2) as total'), 'meatBook.total')
        ->leftJoin('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'sub.id')
        ->leftJoin('bookings', 'bookings.location_id', '=', 'sub.id')
        ->groupBy('sub.location_name');
```

Comment: You'll have to use DB::raw() for the case statement -- Eloquent doesn't support that. The rest of the query is doable, though I don't know off-hand how to do the `sum() from()` part.

Comment: can you give us some base to work on? and a few words about what you trying to get? I will start by spliting this queries to two seperate

Comment: @amir bar I have added a short description to my post about what the query does.  However, I don't know what other information you need.  I simply want to use Laravel-5 Eloquent builder to rebuild this query so that I can easily add new where() statements if I so need.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First of all

I often see people asking for how to rebuild a complex SQL query in Laravels Query Builder. But not every operation which is possible in SQL or MySQL is implemented as a function in Laravels Query Builder. This means you can't rebuild *every* SQL query in Query Builder without using raw SQL.

#### What does this mean for your SQL query?

Some things like sub queries (the `from (select ...)` part) and the `case when ...` part is not implemented in Query Builder. At least therefore you will have to use the raw expression with the `DB::raw()` function. I'm not sure about the `sum()` if this is already possible but you will surely find that in the docs.

Other things like `joins` are implemented as a function:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
                 ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
                 ->select('users.id', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
                 ->get();
```

see Laravel Documentation: [Queries - Joins](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins)

And you can even mix up Query Builder functions with raw expressions:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();
```

see Laravel Documentation: [Queries - Raw Expression](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions)

Example for a sub query:

```php
$subQuery = DB::table('locations')
                 ->leftJoin('bookings', 'locations.id', '=', 'bookings.location_id')
                 ->leftJoin('vouchers', 'bookings.voucher_code', '=', 'vouchers.voucher_code')
                 ->select('locations.id', 'locations.location_name', 'bookings.places');

$query = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()} as sub"))
                 ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
                 ->select(...)
                 ->rightJoin(...)
                 ->groupBy('sub.location_name')
                 ->get();
```

So you can rebuild some parts of the query in Query Builder and use raw expressions wherever you need to.

To debug a query while you build it Laravels [query logging](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging) function can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't really explain how I can implement the sub queries.  Would I add another `->select()` containing the sub query?  If so, where do I add it?

Comment: I added an example for a sub query, but still left some work for you ;)

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I am using.  However it's giving me an `unknown column` error.  Not sure how to fix this?

Comment: I guess you will have to use a raw statement here too for the `sum()` like you did in the `case when` part.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to add another sub query.  I've updated my question with the latest Laravel code i'm using but I get unknown column error.  However, if I remove the second subquery (`meatBookQuery`) it works.  Any ideas? @Peh

Comment: There is no column id in the sub query sub. Maybe you mean meatBook.id or something like that?